# How to Add filter index with alias name in ui component of grid magento2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I created my custom module with admin grid, then i tried to add `order increment id` to my custom grid by altering the grid collection with alias name.

The `order id` is displaying in grid. Now, if I try to filter by `increment_id` , then  it throws an error. Without alias its working fine, if i add alias and try to filter at that time it throws the error.

Following is my code:

```
     <column name="order_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="filter_index" xsi:type="string">o.increment_id</item>
                    <item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order ID</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">75</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

`app\code\Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Test\Grid\Collection.php`

```
protected function _initSelect()
    {
         parent::_initSelect();
         $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            ['o' => 'sales_order_grid'],
            "(o.entity_id = main_table.id)",
            [
                'o.increment_id as order_id'
            ]
        );
    //$this->printLogQuery(true);
        return $this;
    }
```

So please tell how can I add the `filter_index` in magento2 with UI Component ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got it by using the `addFiltertoMap`

Which is defined in

`app\code\Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Test\Grid\Collection.php`

```
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->addFilterToMap(
        'order_id',
        'o.increment_id'
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this method into following class

```
app\code\Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Test\Grid\Collection.php
```

```
public function addFieldToFilter($field, $condition = null)
{
    if ($field === 'order_id') {
        // custom condition
        return;
    }

    return parent::addFieldToFilter($field, $condition);
}
```

Comment: best way is addFilterToMap